# Getting this error : Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:
        [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        if let isDynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks() .shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
            return handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: What is the return type of `shouldHandleDynamicLink` method?

Comment: boolean return type

Comment: Then you don't need to optional-chain it.

Comment: What is the return type of `dynamicLinks()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>⌥-click</kbd> on `shouldHandleDynamicLink` and you will see the declaration

> ```
> func shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL url: URL) -> Bool
> ```

The return type is non-optional. Remove the optional binding

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:
    [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().shouldHandleDynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
        let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url)
        return handleDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
    }
    return true
}
```